# when is else statement in loops needed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am confused on when is else clause executed. I am trying to write a piece of code to test if a number is prime or not. Under my "if" statement, when x%n==0, I break the loop. Is the else statement still going to run? What is the correct translation of if...else..., for....else, while...else? When do I need it?

```
def is_prime(x):
  if x<2:
    return False
  if x==2:
    return True
  for n in range(2,x):
    if x%n==0:
      return False
      break
    else:
      return True
```

Comment: if you return you do not need to write break. it will return the value from that line. next lines will never executed.

Comment: Also, if you do _either_ a `break` or a `return`, the loop is over, so the `else` statement well never run, nor will any later `if`s.

Comment: There _is_ a `for…else` (and `while…else`) in Python. The `else` clause runs if you fell off the end of the loop, without ever doing a `break`. This is sometimes useful when you can't just `return` early, but not necessary for your case.

Comment: @Atiq, if I erase the break statement, input x=9 returns True. It seems like it went to the else statement.

Comment: @JingLi for which input?

Comment: @Atiq I tried x=9, which is not a prime, but the code returned True

Comment: yes because in else block you return true. so when n = 2 it tried x % n == 0 so its False and execute else block and return True.

Comment: @Atiq so the loop still executes the else stament after the if statement is run.

Comment: its not the loop. its if/else block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `else` clause on a loop will be entered if the loop exited without a `break` statement.  In a for-loop, this usually means you iterated past the final item.  In a while-loop, it means the while "test" failed.

A couple of useful tips for not getting confused about which way the `else` flow on a loop works:

- Should the loop break inside a conditional, the `else` is like an else on the `if`.
- Should a `while` loop terminate because of failure of the while "test", you may imagine replacing the `while` keyword with an `if` in that final iteration.

Examples where the else *will* be executed:

```
for x in 'abc':
    if x == 'z':
        break
else:
    # this will be executed, because we don't hit a break

for x in []:
    break
else:
    # this will be executed, because we don't hit a break

while False:
    break
else:
    # this will be executed, because we don't hit a break
```

Examples where the else *won't* be executed:

```
for x in 'abc':
    if x == 'b':
        break
else:
    # this will not be executed, because we hit a break

n = 0
while True:
    if n > 10:
        break
    n += 1
else:
    # this will not be executed, because we hit a break

for x in 'abc':
    if x == 'b':
        return  # assuming we're inside a function here
else:
    # this will not be executed, because flow did not exit the loop
    # (`for:else` is not like `finally`!)

while True:
    pass
else:
    # this will not be executed, and your CPU is overheating
```

Comment: Why does else loop not executed in this loop? if n=0, why does the if loop still run? while True:
    if n > 10:
        break
    n += 1
else:
    # this will not be executed, because we hit a break

Comment: You answered your own question there!  `n` gets incremented until the break hits.

Answer (score 1):

The reason to use `for…else` or `while…else` is when you have code that needs to be run if you fell off the end of the loop without a `break` statement. Usually this means you were testing each value for some condition, with a `break` on success, but never succeeded:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(lst):
    if val in good_vals:
        break
else:
    print("Couldn't find a good value")
    return None
print(f"Found good value {val} at position {idx}")
return do_something_with(idx)
```

But in simple cases, like the one above—and like yours—you can always rewrite things to make the `else` unnecessary:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(lst):
    if val in good_vals:
        print(f"Found good value {val} at position {idx}")
        return do_something_with(idx)
print("Couldn't find a good value")
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you don't need return True on else, look at this example:

```
x = 9
for n = 2,8
when n = 2 the if statement will be 9%2==0 which is False so will return 
True on else statement.
```

The correct function will look like this

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    if x==2:
        return True
    for n in range(2,x):
        if x%n==0:
            return False
            break
    return True
```

This is the correct form, if in your entire for loop didn't return False means that number is prime so return True. Also you can take for range until sqrt(x) instead of x.

Comment: Thank you for the example of 9%2, I didn't realize that the loop worked this way with the booleans! I thought the loop runs until it hit 9%3==0, Question: why sqrt(x)?

Comment: If we try x=9, then sqrt9=3, if the loop is only tested in (2,3), then we are only testing 9%2==0 which is false, then we will not hit break, so we are returning true? But 9 is not prime.

Comment: My bad, i didn't was clear enough, it has to be <= than sqrt(x) so the loop would be 'for n in range(2, math.sqrt(x)+1):'

Answer (score 0):

Because in else block you `return True`. When `n = 2` it tried `x % n == 0` and its false as a result it execute else block and `return True`.

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    if x==2:
        return True
    for n in range(2,x):
        if x%n==0:
          return False
    return True
```